# Databound Canvas control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, canvas

Is it possible to have the controls on a canvas be bound to a list of objects?  I am thinking something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyControlConverter}}"></ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Canvas ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}">
</Canvas>
```

Where MyItems is this:

```
public List<Tuple<ControlType, Point>> MyItems;
```

Basically, there would be a converter that converted each Tuple object to a control at the given Point coordinates on the canvas.  I know that there isn't an "ItemsSource" or "ItemsTemplate" property on the Canvas control, but is this possible in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add a listbox and set its itemspanel to be a canvas.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Canvas/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```